# Report Scheduling for other users not showing options?

Tags: reporting

While Scheduling a report when we select a  "To me and/or others..." radio button, we used to get multi select picklist, where it would show all the users in available fields but I am not getting this option in "Chrome Browser"
(Chrome result)
[image]

when I tried the same thing in "Firefox" it showing only admin user not the other Users(Firefox result)
[image]

Is it a Browser Issue ? Or is there any Spring 14 new option i need to enable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a known issue, details here: https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T40WAAS.

Comment: In FireFox also I am getting the same result only admin user is showing up

Comment: In Firefox, you're getting the admin user because it only lists users that have access to that report folder, please see this knowledge article: http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000006129&language=en_US